# Custom UITableViewCell abandoned memory issue on Select

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, memory

I'm having an issue on iOS using a custom UITableView with a custom UITableViewCell. When I run the app on the Xcode Instruments I can see that there is an abandoned memory issue each time I select a cell from the custom TableView.
Please see the below a screen shot of the "Instruments".

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKz22.png

Below is the code used to create a cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath2:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *cellIdentifier =  [NSString stringWithFormat :@"cellID%i",indexPath.row];

    customViewCell *cell = (customViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


    if (cell == nil) {

        NSInteger cellIndex = [indexPath row];
        NSString* cellName = @"cell Name";

        NSString* keyFile = @"0_48_video_1F0423D5-D2D7-466E-8D45-38C46E9B4425.mp4_1423522824.133377";

        cell = [[customViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier withKeyFile:keyFile andRicochetName:ricochetName fromTableViewController:self;
    }

    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
}
```

I would appreciate any expertise on helping identifying the memory issue. Please note that the App is built on ARC.

Thanks a lot

Comment: why are you creating PRXRicViewCell new instance why don't you use this class in Interface Builder UITableViewCell as subclass

Comment: thanks for your feedback Shashi. Sorry I actually cleanup the code and replace "PRXRicViewCell" to "customViewCell", but to your point customViewCell is a subclass of UITableViewCell.

Comment: Do you want play some video on load UITableViewCell? Can let me know what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: How many rows are there?  And where are your custom tableview cells defined - in a Storyboard or in a XIB? A couple of oddities: `1)` You seem to be dequeuing a unique cell for each row. `2)` The method `tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath` is named wrongly as there is an extra `2` after `cellForRowAtIndexPath` so the method posted will never be called.

Comment: @Sashi, that is correct. each custom cell do load a AVPlayer to play a small video. Similar to Vines or Instagram. KeyFile is a parameter used to load a unique video.

Comment: @RoboticCat. Right now there are 5 rows. But the app is intended to have much more rows. The custom table view cell are defined in the Storyboard  as a Custom cell class of a custom TableView. Could you elaborate your point 1) about dequeuing a unique cell. Regarding your point 2), sorry about that it is because I was doing some testing. I do call the function without the "2"

Comment: @Yacine: If each tableview cell is the same (but just contains different content) then you only need 1 prototype cell which iOS duplicates and then re-uses. This is very, very efficient and fundamental to how to use `UITableView`s. However, if you give each tableview cell a unique name (e.g. `cellID1`, `cellID2` etc..) like you are doing then the cells can never be re-used and you will rapidly run out of memory for any reasonably sized data set. Accordingly, I would expect you to design 1 tableview cell in your Storyboard, give it a name (`videoCell`) and then use for your reuse identifier.

Comment: @Yacine: As an aside, since you define your custom `UITableViewCell` in a storyboard (a good idea) then the code in your `if (cell == nil) { ... }` will never be called and should be removed. This is because `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` is guaranteed  to return a non-nil cell. Also, note that there is a slightly newer version of this you should call instead called `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`.

Comment: @Yacine: Finally, despite allocations continually rising, are you sure the memory is abandoned? You are not re-using tableview cells so are you sure you are releasing memory? Are you adding `CALayer`s anywhere? Can you add an image and the code for your custom tableview cell? And if you want to disable the blue selection of cells, you can try `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` and remove the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: @RoboticCat: thanks a lot for your input. I did modify the code to apply the single prototype cell and reuse it with a static cell Identifier: "cellID". I can see an improvement in the abandoned memory which is great, but I'm still not there yet as I can still see some abandoned memory that is not free. Also to your 2nd point the apps does return a  instantiated cell so if I remove the if(cell ==nil) {...} the application crashes. Maybe I have something wrongly configured there. Finally, you guess right anf the cell do add an image and a AVplayer. do yo think that this is where the issue is?

Comment: @Yacine: Make sure you are using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`. The docs guarantee a non-nil cell (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:). The problem could be in the cell - can you update the question with new Allocations output, the new `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` an image of your storyboard custom cell and any code relating to the custom cell.

Comment: Thanks Robotic Cat. Seems like my TableCell has several issues, but with all your inputs guys I do see some improvements and have different track to investigate. I will mark this ticket as resolved and do some additional homework on the custom cell and open a new one is I can not resolved it. FYI I did try dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: but it seems the app can't find the cell prototype in the storyboard, it is configured though:"  'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier cellID - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just have to pass keyFile name you use this way. Make sure you have linked keyFile in interface builder

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath2:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *cellIdentifier =  @"cellID";
    customViewCell *cell = (customViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        NSInteger cellIndex = [indexPath row];
        NSString* cellName = @"cell Name";

        NSString* keyFile = @"0_48_video_1F0423D5-D2D7-466E-8D45-38C46E9B4425.mp4_1423522824.133377";
        cell.keyFile=keyFile;


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shashi,I tried the above but doing this I am getting the following error:"UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:" . This is because the cell is not getting allocated. So r u saying that the cell allocation should be managed somewhere else?

Comment: check in interface builder you would not have linked customViewCell class and also check you have cell identifier name cellID or not?

Comment: So indeed the cell identifier was missing, I now added it and confirm that the customeViewCell is properly setup on the Interface Builder. However I still have to instantiate the cell to work.  But one thing I noticed now, is that with a static cell Identifier name, It now reduces the number of abandoned memory to a max of 2! I'm not sure why 2, but now when I click on each 5 rows, a total of 2 created and never released. Before it was a total of 5 (one for each row). So there is a good improvement.

Comment: Reusable cell is basically it uses the instance of cell from Interface builder and create new one and it creates up to number of your cells are visible and when you scroll if the cell is not created in previous scroll it will create new or if the cell is created in previous scroll it will not create it will re use the cell. I hope it helps. Can mark as correct answer or vote me?

Comment: Thanks Shashi. Your help was very precious on this and I your unput help a lot. I did apply the design you mentioned which improve the memory issue.

Answer (score 0):

change the cell identifier to a static string.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath2:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        static NSString *cellIdentifier =  @"your tableview Cell Identifier";

        customViewCell *cell = (customViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


        if (cell == nil) {
            NSString* cellName = @"cell Name";

            NSString* keyFile = @"0_48_video_1F0423D5-D2D7-466E-8D45-38C46E9B4425.mp4_1423522824.133377";

            cell = [[customViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier withKeyFile:keyFile andRicochetName:ricochetName fromTableViewController:self;
        }

        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Vineesh for helping on this. Using a static Cell identifier do improve the abandoned memory issue. Now It limits the issue to 2 selected cell instances that are never released. I also had to change the way I instantiate the cell to  set the cell properties after it ben allocated.